# How to close and open and browser using protractor + angular js

Tags: javascript

**My scenario**

1. login to the application and close the browser.
2. Reopen the browser
3. validate that the user is on the login page.

**Issue**
I am closing the browser using: `browser.quit()`
After that, I need to reopen the browser.

**My Problem**
When I call `browser.driver.get(url)` it throws an error saying:

> no active session.

How to handle this situation?

Comment: Please note that I am using Chrome browser for testing.